# GetElementById with CefSharp

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, cefsharp

I'm trying to access to a website variable by it's ID in VB.net. The ID is "value", the data I'm trying to access is the stock price, and the website is linked in the code. I was using the built-in web browser with the next code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net

Public Class Bolsa
  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.ahorro.com/acnet/fichas/ficha_valor.acnet?isin=ES0113211835&marketCode=09&submarketId=09")
    While Not WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
      Application.DoEvents()
    End While

    Dim request As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("value").InnerText
    Dim s As String = request.Replace("<span>", Nothing)
    Dim t As String = s.Replace("</span>", Nothing)

    TextBox1.Text = t
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I'm using CefSharp plugin, because I need HTML5 support, but I cannot access the data, and I think the method is correct, I found it in the official site. The actual code:

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Treading
Imports System.Treading.Tasks

Public Class Bolsa
  Private WithEvents WebClave As ChromiumWebBrowser
  Dim cadena

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
  End Sub
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
    WebClave = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.ahorro.com/acnet/fichas/ficha_valor.acnet?isin=ES0113211835&marketCode=09&submarketId=09")
    pANwEB.Controls.Add(WebClave)
  End Sub

  Private Sub WebClave_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(sender As Object, e As IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs) Handles WebClave.IsBrowserInitializedChanged
    If e.IsBrowserInitialized Then
      cadena = WebClave.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('value').innerHTML")
      TextBox1.Text = cadena
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Any advice? 
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: Added full original code

Comment: Read the general usage guide, Google and you'll find it. The page won't have loaded or the browser even been initialized in your example

Comment: The examples aren't the full code. In both cases the website is fully loaded and functional, and the first method, using the built-in web browser, works perfectly, I get all the data I need, but some graphics doesn't work as they are in HTML5. Using CefSharp I can load the website perfectly, but when I try to access the variable using the code in example I get a blank response or get an error.

Comment: So you have a problem with code that's different to that which you provide as a sample of the code your having a problem with?

Comment: Added both full codes

Comment: Read the general usage guide, browser initialized is way too early to be expecting JavaScript. You should also pay attention as you've not executed the actual task.

Answer (score 2):

Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms

Public Class Form1
    Public WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com") With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cvbar = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById(""lst-ib"").value;")
    Dim response = cvbar.Result
    If response.Success = True And response.Result <> "" Then
        MsgBox(response.Result)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class